# エラーの意味を教えてください: module 'ecdsa' has no attribute 'SigningKey'

Tags: python, python3

```
module 'ecdsa' has no attribute 'SigningKey'
```

こんな文のエラーが出ます。
何をすればいいのでしょうか

Comment: 同じエラーでも違う対処が必要なことはよくあるので、そのエラーがでるソースコードを、可能な範囲で良いので質問文に追記して下さいませんか？

Comment: 質問文編集しました。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: matu-nn さん、編集の前後でご質問の内容が変わってしまい、Yasuhiro さんの回答が無下になってしまっています。「編集日時」のところをクリックして編集をリバートした後、別の質問としてご投稿ください。（リバートの方法が分からなければ私が代わりに行いますので、遠慮なくおっしゃってください。）

Comment: すみません。質問しなおします。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

実行しているディレクトリー内に、'ecdsa.py'という名前のファイル又は'ecdsa'という名前のフォルダーを作成していないでしょうか。そうすると'import ecdsa'で'ecdsa'パッケージではなくディレクトリー内の'ecdsa'をインポートしてしまいます。

'ecdsa'がどこからインポートされたかは以下で確認できます。

```
print(ecdsa.__path__)
```